# Swig for loop with Nodejs, Express,

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

I'm trying to create a loop to access array object with swig.

I want to create a loop that checks the length of the object. i can access the objects by {{styles[0].style}}. where [] is an array. so what i need to do is to have something like

```
for (var i; i < styles.length; i++) { styles[i].style };
```

if there are ten arrays in styles object, i need to show off {{styles[0].style}}, {{styles[1].style}}, ... {{styles[9].style}}

here is the code that i want to put my {{}}:

```
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><td><a href={{styles[0].a}}><div style="width: 175px;height: 250px" id="products">
<img id="img" src={{styles[0].img}}></div></a></td></tr><tr><td id="styleno">{{styles[0].style}}
</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i think would need something like:

```
{% for x in y %}
{% if loop.first %}<ul>{% endif %}
<li>{{ loop.index }} - {{ loop.key }}: {{ x }}</li>
{% if loop.last %}</ul>{% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

can anyone please help? Thanks!

here's my JSON:

```
{
"styles":[
          {"style":"123", "a":"http://", "img":"http://", "price":3},
          {"style":"234", "a":"http://", "img":"http://", "price":2}
         ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an if statement to check the length of the `styles` item...

In swig@1.0.0-pre1

```
{% if styles and styles.length === 10 %}
<table border="1">
<tbody>
  {% for style in styles %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="{{ style.a }}">
        <div style="width:175px; height:250px;" id="products">
          <img id="img" src="{{ style.img }}">
        </div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i can only access to my JSON by styles[0].style this format..any other idea?

Comment: You'll need to actually post your JSON, because I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: i uploaded my JSON Thanks!

Comment: @wisleans The example that I gave you will work. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Ah! i found it.. i was wondering why only {{ style.img}} would work.. you have a typo on <a href=> .. Thanks!!

Comment: i have another question. is it possible to give a condition to a loop? such as if styles and styles.length === 4 add new a <tr> or     var j = styles.length;                                              if(j%4 == 0 && j != 0){
    newTable.appendChild(tr);
    tr = document.createElement('tr');        
}

Comment: @PaulArmstrong the swig documentation on github has vanished, it's understood that swig is no longer maintained but keep the documentation of the latest version at least so that people who are stuck with projects already using swig can actually read about it. Thanks